# Why I cannot find javadoc of BufferedWriter?

Tags: java, netbeans

I use NetBeans to write my Java code. Usually I can move the mouse on some keywords and press 'Alt'+'F1' to bring up the javadoc of the keyword.

But for BufferedWriter, NetBeans shows "cannot find symbol", why?

Comment: works fine with netbeans 7.1.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the code compile without error, or does it refuse? If you can't compile the code, make sure you have:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
```

at the start of the code, otherwise Netbeans won't be certain which class the token "BufferedWriter" means, so it won't be able to work out which Javadoc belongs to that class.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the real reason for me.